# MatPaginator en multiples tablas

Tags: angular, angular-material

estoy intentando hacer un matpaginator para multiples tablas traidas de una misma funcion pero el matpaginator aparece como 'undefined'

[image: vista]

De esta manera tengo mi funcion en el `component.ts` que trae los datos desde un servicio

```
Groups(){
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
this.apiSvc.Cards().subscribe((rsp: any) => { 
    this.groups = rsp;
    
});

this.apiSvc.Cards().pipe(
    switchMap((rsp:any[])=>{
        return forkJoin(
            rsp.map(x=>this.apiSvc.Groups(x.id))
            )
        })
).subscribe((res:any[])=>{

    this.dataSource.data = res;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    
 });
```

}

de esta manera declare mi paginator
`@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator = Object.create(null);`

y asi tengo mi template

```
<div id="GroupFor">
 <div fxLayout="row wrap" *ngFor = "let group of groups | searchGroupFilter:searchText">
  //group data
 </div>
</div>
<div fxFlex.gt-lg="82" fxFlex.gt-md="81" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100" id="tableDiv">
 <mat-card class="mat-card-employee">
  <mat-card-content>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource.filteredData | filterGroups:group.id" class="table employee-list no-wrap">
      //rows and columns
    </table>
    <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator> 
   </div>
   </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
 </div>
```

Creo que no trae el mat paginator porque hay multiples tablas y al asignarlo en el metodo `subscribe()` es indefinido.

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agaradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder a todas las instancias de un componente o elementos del template puedes usar el decorador **@ViewChildren**, con el cual obtendrás la lista de instancias de dicho elemento.

Esto se discutió aquí:

[Multiple Mat-Paginator in a single page]
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518541/multiple-mat-paginator-in-a-single-page-angular-5-data-table)

Adicionalmente, puedes revisar la documentación:

[ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Comment: Hola, lo revisare, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!